# Please install ‘NETCFv35.Messages.EN.wm.cab’ for Windows Mobile 5.0 and above or ‘NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab’ for other platforms. Restart the a

Tags: windows-mobile

An error message is available for this exception but cannot be displayed because these messages are optional and are not currently installed on this device. Please install ‘NETCFv35.Messages.EN.wm.cab’ for Windows Mobile 5.0 and above or  ‘NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab’ for other platforms. Restart the application to see the message.
Hey any one know about solution for this......

Answer (score 17):

The device is telling you that you had an exception, but the exception "Message" is not available.  There are a few things to know here:

1. You should be catching exceptions and providing user-meaningful messsages, not the message in the exception itself.  It usually means nothing to a user.
2. You can install the exception messages by installing the indicated CAB file, which can be found here:
   `%PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Diagnostics`
3. A restart isn't actually needed.

Comment: NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab is already installed - I've got message "Microsoft .NET CF 3.5 EN-String resource already installed. Re-install?"

Comment: Are you *certain* it's installed?  I say this because it's possible to install it, which will put the binary in the \Windows folder and then mark it as installed in the registry.  If the registry persists, you may reset the device and the binary goes away, but the registry still says it's installed.

Answer (score 17):

2 Simple Steps:

1) Simply copy the file :

```
NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab
```

from your computer to your device.

The CAB can be found on your own 32-bit Windows system here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Diagnostics
```

On 64-bit systems the file is here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Diagnostics`
```

2) Locate the file on your device, Tap on it from your device and it would install automatically.

Answer (score 3):

- Extract SYCCFA~1.001 from NETCFv35.Messages.XX.wm.cab
- Rename it System.SR.dll
- Add it as reference to your application

From: http://tech.cybernet.lu/?p=522#comment-199

Answer (score 2):

just go to the given path below and download the file...its working...
"sourceforge.net/projects/opencellclient/files/OpenCellClient/V0.3.1-4/NETCFv35.Messages.EN.wm.cab/download?use_mirror=tenet"